# React Native resizeMode:'contain' not working with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-stylesheet

I am working the `resizeMode:'contain'` because the image is stretching. but the resizeMode not working with expo app.

```
image: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 10,
    resizeMode:'contain',
  },


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress({ product })}>
   <Image
     source={{ uri: getProductImage(product.images[0].src, 100) }}
     style={styles.image}
   />
</TouchableOpacity>[enter image description here][1]
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv017.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image 'contain' resizeMode not working in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436913/image-contain-resizemode-not-working-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

try to put `resizeMode='contain'` inside `Image` component:

```js
<Image
     resizeMode='contain'
     source={{ uri: getProductImage(product.images[0].src, 100) }}
     style={styles.image}
   />
```

check also this method using `flex` and `height:undefined':
[example](https://snack.expo.io/As9SgfACb)

Comment: I used the resizeMode={'contain'} like this but still not working.

Comment: use it like this  resizeMode='contain'

Comment: Still not working is there another way to use this. before that was working but after the update node_module the property not working.

Comment: check the example for flex method

Comment: this is fine but I am getting an issue in height of the images. the images are coming from API.

Comment: if images dont have same proportions the result wont be the same even with same height